# Load values from a spreadsheet to tables in Sql Server

Tags: sql, batch-file, import

I have to load (kind of) recipes into a Sql Server database.

I receive recipes in the form of a spreadsheet.

[Spreadsheet with recipes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHVVg.jpg)

The database format for Recipes is like this:

[Database for recipes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUlIg.jpg)

Stored Procedure:

```
set @IdParameter = (select top 1 id_parameter 
                    from Parameters 
                    where pa_code ='Macchina') 

if (select count(*) 
    from Opera6010.dbo.BatParameters (nolock) 
    where id_batch = @IdBatch 
        and id_parameter = @IdParameter) = 0 

begin 
    insert into BatParameters with (rowlock) 
    (id_batch, id_parameter, bp_value) 
    values (@IdBatch, @IdParameter, @Macchina) 
end 

else 
begin 
    update BatParameters with (rowlock) 
    set bp_value = @Macchina  
    where id_batch = @IdBatch 
        and id_parameter = @IdParameter 
end
```

First (not smart, in my opinion) solution has been:

1. import the spreadsheet as a table, same format
2. define a cursor over this table, each "fetch" loads a Recipe ID and a list of values for ingredients.
3. Do a lot of copy, past and replace work to write code like this:

   `set @IdIngredient = (select top 1 ingr_id 
                          from Ingredients 
                          where ingr_desc ='Ingredient1')
     insert into RecIngredients with (rowlock) 
     (recipe_id, ingr_id, value) 
     values (@IdRecipe, @IdIngredient, @Ingredient1)
     set @return_status = @@error`

I am wondering whether a smarter approach exists to create a loop like:

For each row of the input table
  be @RecipeId the value for Recipe ID read from cursor

For each Ingredient
      get column name relative to the value currently read
      get  ingr_id for the Ingredient having ingr_desc like the column name
      set (recipe_id, ingr_id, value) in table RecIngredients

What do you think?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are ever thinking "I've used a cursor and it's not great--so I'm thinking I should add a loop to it" then it's probably time to try for a set-based approach IMO.

Comment: HI Jacob, thank you for your prompt comment. Frankly, the less great thing I see in my procedure is copynig and pasting and replacing 24 times the section where I set the value/quantity of the Ingredient #N.

Comment: Can you show your procedure? It really sounds like you can do this with an update and a join.

Comment: Given IdBatch and IdParameter for respectively, Recipe ID and Parameter ID, I reapeat kind of 20 times the same sequence in the code, just replacing the name of the ingredient and the related variable for its value

Comment: `  set @IdParameter = (select top 1 id_parameter from Parameters where pa_code ='Macchina')
  
  if (select count(*) from Opera6010.dbo.BatParameters (nolock) where id_batch = @IdBatch and id_parameter = @IdParameter) = 0 begin
   insert into BatParameters with (rowlock) (id_batch, id_parameter, bp_value) values (@IdBatch, @IdParameter, @Macchina)
  end else begin
   update BatParameters with (rowlock) 
   set bp_value = @Macchina  
   where id_batch = @IdBatch and id_parameter = @IdParameter
  end 
`

Answer (score 1):

Check out [SeekWell](https://seekwell.io/?ref=so), which lets you update your database from a Google Sheet.  Basically you would `Select` your table to a Sheet, pivot the new recipes you received and append the rows to the `Select`ed table in the Sheet.  Mark the new rows for `Insert` and set the schedule for the update.

You can read more about it [here](https://intercom.help/seekwell/seekwell-desktop/sync-sheets-with-your-database-desktop-app).

Hope that helps!